# How can I use the GitHub Rest API to update a repository that is part of an organization?

Tags: github-api

I have a large number of GitHub repositories that have been sorted into various organizations.  I wish to change the visibility of the repos by batch to public using the following API call:

```sh
curl -u {user}:{pat} -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json"  -X PATCH https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/angular.powershifter -d '{"private":false}'
```

Which as best as I can tell is the API call ([see github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#update-a-repository)). The `{user]` and `{pat}` in the sample above are real values, and the `{pat}` has every option selected.  The `{user}` is both the owner of the repo and the organization.

What I get in response is is a `404` with the following body.

```sh
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/repos#update-a-repository"
}
```

1. **Is it possible to set the properties of repositories under an organization using the API?**
2. **What is the API call?**
3. **Bonus points if you can point me to the documentation!**

Thanks.

Comment: try adding `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`

Comment: that did not help

Answer (score 0):

Use Bearer Token based authentication. Github is deprecating password based authentications.

```
curl \
 -H 'Authorization: Bearer ${GITHUB-TOKEN}' \
 -X PATCH \
 -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
 https://api.github.com/repos/${OWNER}/${repo} \
 -d '{"private":"false"}'
```

Link for the github documentation
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it is possible.
2. I've had some issues with this too.
   Short answer use bearer token (As @shek said), and change false to "false":

   curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" 
   -X PATCH [https://api.github.com/repos/${ORGANIZATION}/${REPO}](https://api.github.com/repos/$%7BORGANIZATION%7D/$%7BREPO%7D)
   -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" -d '{"private": "false"}';

Notice that your token has full control of private repositories when creating the token:
[full control of private repositories image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlADU.png)

The link is quite confusing, because if for example you need to get all the repositories from GitHub you'll have to use:

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/${ORGANIZATION}/repos?${parameters}
```

Also when you need to change permissions you'll need to use:

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/${ORGANIZATION}/teams/${TEAM}/repos/${ORGANIZATION}/${REPO}
```

(Notice the orgs, which is missing in the PATCH command).

3. GitHub repositories documentation:
   https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#update-a-repository
   GitHub auth methods (From @shek):
   https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods